# Sequence of numbers with multiples of 10

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want show numbers in dropdown like 0,10,20,30,40,60,70

For it I write

```
0..70
```

But it generate all numbers from 0 to 70 .I want only multiples of 10

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a look at [`Numeric.step`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Numeric.html#method-i-step).

```
0.step(70,10).to_a
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to `Numeric.step`

```
0.step(70,10).to_a
```

you can also use `Range#step`:

```
Range.new(0,70).step(10).to_a
(0..70).step(10).to_a
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a new Enumerator for this:

```
multiples_of_10 = Enumerator.new do |y|
    x = 0
    loop do
        y << x
        x += 10
    end
end

multiples_of_10.take(8) # => [0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70]
```